# Backbone - populate collection from json and update view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, firebug, backbone-events, backbone-views

I am trying to populate a collection with data from a JSON file. I'm a backbone beginner, so my problems are probably easy to solve. But have struggled with this all day - so now I'm asking for guidance.

I am creating a questionnaire, and want to load the questions from a JSON file stored locally (I will get the questions from a server later).

I am not sure if my collection gets populated at all, or if the problem is that the view doesn't update. I have read a lot of tutorials and have got some ideas from different places.

Well.. this is my javascript code:

```
$(function(){

var Question = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        q: "Empty question..."
    },

    initialize: function() {
        if (!this.get("q")) {
            this.set({"q": this.defaults.q});
        }
    }
});


var QuestionList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Question,
    url: "question.json"
});

var Questions = new QuestionList;


var QuestionView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:  "li",

    template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'remove');
        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});


var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $("#questionnaire_app"),

    itemTemplate: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll', 'render');

        Questions.bind('reset',   this.addAll);
        Questions.fetch();
    },

    addOne: function(question) {
        var view = new QuestionView({model: question});
        this.$("#question-list").append(view.render().el);
    },

    addAll: function() {
        Questions.each(this.addOne);
    }
});

var App = new AppView;

});
```

And I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="questionnaire_app">
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Questions</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="questions">
            <ul id="question-list"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/template" id="item-template">
    <div class="question">
        <div class="display">
            <p class="question-content"><%= q %></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

The JSON file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "q": "How were your meeting with Dr. Apfelstrudel?"
    },
    {
        "q": "What do you think of the movie Die Hard 4.0"
    },
    {
        "q": "Are people from Mars really green?"
    }
]
```

**Bonus question:** I use firebug, but find it very difficult to debug this stuff. If i e.g write `console.log(Questions);` in the console do I get **ReferenceError: Questions is not defined**. Why is that?

**UPDATE:** Problem solved. I didn't use a web server before, which I do now (I just opened the file in the browser). The code works fine.

Comment: new QuestionList() is prob the solution to your reference error

Comment: @Alex it isn't necessary to add the () at the end.

Comment: Is there something else your missing, your code runs fine by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it seems to run fine by me.

**EDIT**: Here's a link to a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rzYLU/) with your code, just modified that instead of fetching the models I manually add the list (since I don't see how i can duplicate that in the jsfiddle). Maybe your problem is with your JSON file (read only, wrong location).

The reason why you get a reference error in firebug is because the questions reference going out of scope at the end of the document ready function, if you assign it to something you will be able to log it.

For example

```
var q = {};

$(function() {

  // Your code
  var Questions = new QuestionList;
   q.Questions = Questions
 //the rest of your code
});
```

Now you can log it in firebug using console.log(q.Questions);

Comment: Thank you:) Now I can log Questions, and confirm it is empty! The collection has not been populated. Maybe there is some other problem. Do you really get the questions rendered in the view?

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle. I can see it works when you manually add the questions. I don't use a web server, I just open the file in the browser, and the json file is in the same directory. Do you think that is a problem? I don't see a ajax call in the firebug console (which I actually expect).

Comment: I first tried it on a development server on my local machine with the JSON file in the same directory (which worked).

Comment: I also tested it now just by opening the file in a browser and it also renders the questions (however I don't see any Ajax requests either, but I'm not sure that there should be one).